# Can't send async post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

I'm trying to await post request. I've found `request-promise-native` package to make await requests. It works for GET requests but doesn't work with the POST. The URL is working, the auth hash is working as well as I've tested it with `curl.

```
import * as request from "request-promise-native";

async sendRequest(uri: string, method: string): Promise<any> {
    var options = {
        uri: uri,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Basic ' + 'someValidHashValue'
        },
        method: method,
        json: true
    };

    try {
        const result = await request.get(options);
        return result;
    }
    catch (err) {

        console.log(err);
    }
}

async queueBambooPlan(fileName: string) {
    let bambooHost: string | undefined = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('markdown-table-of-contents').get('atlassianBambooHost');
    let planKey = await this.getBambooPlanKey(fileName, bambooHost);
    let uri = `${bambooHost}/rest/api/latest/queue/${planKey}`;

    let response = await this.sendRequest(uri, 'post');
}
```

> 405 - "Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 - Error
>   reportH1
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
>   H2
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
>   H3
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}
>   BODY
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
>   B
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A
>   {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px;
>   background-color: #525D76; border: none;}
>
> ## HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>   Method Not Allowed
>
> **description** The specified
>   HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/8.0.36

The request from above worked using `fiddler`, however it is not working from the code.

[image]

UPDATE: I've wrote the code using standard request package and it is working:

[image]

Comment: You can only `await` inside of an async function... just throwing that out there. So the line `await this.sendRequest()` is invalid.

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: The error message means your server doesn't accept POST requests on that url.

Comment: Updated the question, the URL is right and it is working using fiddler or curl

Comment: Might want to verify that the uri you're using in your code matches that which works in Fiddler.

Comment: Most likely something's not working in your code, as Chris mentioned above, please double check the uri. Maybe it's different and that's why it works. If they are the same, then try to check your logs. Use try/catch :)

Comment: I've copy/pasted it from vs code to fiddler

Comment: well... HTTP 4xx errors are client-sided errors. That means something in your code is not working. Please place your function inside a try/catch and post the error message (if you get one).

Comment: I've added screenshot using standard request package and it is working

Comment: I see, please post the link to the package you're using so I can check the documentation :) EDIT: please check Brent's answer, I didn't happen to notice that, but it seems to be the actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `request.get`, use `request.post` instead or simply use `request(options)` with the `method` property set.